# search highlighting only in the current buffer

Tags: search, buffers, highlight

I know that I can run a search in vim using `/`. I prefer having search highlighting turned on, but if I have a two splits with different files open, and I search for a term in one, they get highlighted as if I ran the same search or subsitution in both. Is there any way to disable this? The same thing occurs with tabs as well.

Comment: not possible. `hlsearch` will always highlight all windows. There is an open issue/todo item about changing it to a local option. I remember having looked into it and it wasn't that easy.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this isn’t possible. However, I found this neat mini-plugin in [Paul Irish’s vimrc](https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) which does something close to what you’re looking for. As it stands, it highlights occurrences of the current word but I’m sure it could be updated to highlight a given string. Just add it to your vimrc and hit 1-6 to highlight the word under cursor in various colors.

```
  " This mini-plugin provides a few mappings for highlighting words temporarily.
  "
  " Sometimes you're looking at a hairy piece of code and would like a certain
  " word or two to stand out temporarily.  You can search for it, but that only
  " gives you one color of highlighting.  Now you can use <leader>N where N is
  " a number from 1-6 to highlight the current word in a specific color.

  " credit: https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

  function! HiInterestingWord(n) " {{{
    " Save our location.
    normal! mz

    " Yank the current word into the z register.
    normal! "zyiw

    " Calculate an arbitrary match ID.  Hopefully nothing else is using it.
    let mid = 86750 + a:n

    " Clear existing matches, but don't worry if they don't exist.
    silent! call matchdelete(mid)

    " Construct a literal pattern that has to match at boundaries.
    let pat = '\V\<' . escape(@z, '\') . '\>'

    " Actually match the words.
    call matchadd("InterestingWord" . a:n, pat, 1, mid)

    " Move back to our original location.
    normal! `z
  endfunction " }}}

  " Mappings {{{
  nnoremap <silent> <leader>1 :call HiInterestingWord(1)<cr>
  nnoremap <silent> <leader>2 :call HiInterestingWord(2)<cr>
  nnoremap <silent> <leader>3 :call HiInterestingWord(3)<cr>
  nnoremap <silent> <leader>4 :call HiInterestingWord(4)<cr>
  nnoremap <silent> <leader>5 :call HiInterestingWord(5)<cr>
  nnoremap <silent> <leader>6 :call HiInterestingWord(6)<cr>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It might be useful to include a link to where you got this from. Also, note that the "id" for `matchadd()` is optional (and `matchadd` returns the ID for removing it later), so you can establish the highlight and clear it. Lastly, why the autocmd dance at the top? It never closes (`augroup END`) or sets up actual auto commands...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, first post so definitely appreciated! Yes, you can clear highlight later using the same command <leader># which is useful. 

The original source is in the code as comment: https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc, I added to the answer to clarify. 

As for augroup, good question. I never even noticed that was there to be honest, don’t think there’s a good reason for it (at least not that I can think of). I mis-copied and left off the augroup end, which should be on the last line.

Comment: Seems like it could be useful to either [edit] in the missing code, or remove it if it's not needed.

Comment: (Based on a glance through his vimrc, he really doesn't grok the purpose of autcommands, or he's doing something really bizarre. Not a pattern I'd copy, especially if any one is new to vim.)

Comment: Good point, I’ll edit the posted code. To be honest, I pulled this snippet out back in the day when I was new to vim and didn’t really get what was going on. It’s worked for me ever since so I haven’t had a reason to even look at this code in a few years.